# checking isomorphism between K regular graph

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, graph-isomorphism, symmetry

**Problem** Input is a k regular graph of n vertices and I have to check whether this is isomorphic to another given k regular graph G. This is a restricted version of graph isomorphism in the sense that given graph G is constructed from a p-dimension hypercube graph H<sub>p</sub> of 2n vertices [ so n is a power of 2 ] as ...

Since hypercube is always bipartite.[ H<sub>p</sub> = (L,R),V ] 
G has n nodes corresponding to the left set L of H<sub>p</sub>. 
For any 2 nodes in L which have a path of length 2 in H<sub>p</sub>, there is an edge between the corresponding nodes in G.

It is easy to see that G is regular and highly symmetric [in term diameter,no of diameters etc due to properties of hypergraph ].

My problem is how to detect whether the input graph can be constructed from a hypercube graph as shown or not . i.e. efficiently check for isomorphism.

**Note** For a given (n,k) there can be many regular graph as shown in http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/markus/reggraphs.html

Comment: If you really know that graph isomorphism is NP-hard, your knowledge vastly surpasses the rest of humanity.

Comment: Our of curiosity, what is the motivation behind this question?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek , sorry for my bad mistake, I have corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

If $p$ is fixed, graph isomorphism can be tested in polynomial time, see [E. Luks. Isomorphism of graphs of bounded valance can be tested in polynomial time. Journal of Computer and System Sciences, 25:42–65, 1982].